# Send a method from `object.method` string

Tags: ruby

I want to run the same process inside a block on data coming from different sources. The methods from which I obtain the elements to search in have different names. This is an example of what I want to do:

```
def search_in(list, i)
  send(list) { |s| puts s if s.include?(i) }
end
```

Then I would like to call it like the following:

`search_in("contents.each", i)` or `search_in("@things.entries", i)`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why doesn't your current solution work?

Comment: @sawa I don't know how to achieve this since send doesn't allow to give the name of target object into its parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`send` just sends a message (method call) to a receiver. You're specifying the *receiver* as part of the string, which means you'll have to do some wizardry to extract it properly. You're probably doing something you shouldn't here, though - I would encourage you to elaborate on your question to get advice on how to refactor it to avoid this particular operation.

However, to solve this, you'll need to extract and resolve the receiver, extract the message, and then send the message to the receiver. You should probably avoid eval.

Given a string, `list`

```
# Split the string into something that should resolve to the receiver, and the method to send
receiver_str, method = list.split(".", 2)

# Look up possible receivers by looking in instance_methods and instance_variables.
# Note that this isn't doing any constant resolution or anything; the assumption
# is that the receiver is visible in the current scope.
if instance_methods.include?(receiver_str)
  receiver = send(receiver_str)
elsif instance_variables.include?(receiver_str)
  receiver = instance_variable_get(receiver_str)
else
  raise "Bad receiver: #{receiver_str}"
end

receiver.send(method) {|s| ... }
```

Given that this is a static block though, you expect an Enumerable to be passed; rather than passing a string to resolve into a receiver and method, you should try to pass the Enumerable itself:

```
def search_enumerable_for(enum, i)
  enum.each {|e| puts e if e.include?(i) }
end

search_enumerable_for(contents, value)
search_enumerable_for(@things.entries, value)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, Chris. In fact I am making a playlist manager and i want to have two functions : add a song to a playlist and remove song from a playlist. It would take a song title in parameter, but my code for add and remove is quite similar (there is a menu to handle multiple matchings, etc) excepted two elements. In particular, it searches for matchings in the playlist when removing and in the whole song db when adding, putting them in an array. So I wanted to avoid code duplication by creating a function called differently given the context, since each function was 40 lines long.

Comment: In that case, simply make your methods accept the object which contains the list of songs and perform your operation on it, rather than a string referring to what the object is referred to in your code.